# stored procedure for search string with firstname name

Tags: sql

i need query which starts with first name here is my query:

```
if(@firstName <> '')

BEGIN 
 set @queryString = @queryString+ ' and UPPER(col_FirstName) like ''%' +@firstName +'%'''
END
if(@lastName <> '')
BEGIN 

set @queryString = @queryString + ' and UPPER(col_LastName) like ''%' +@lastName +'%'''
```

but it is searching first name in middle also i want to search only with initials letters
thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with the queyr you posted? Any errors?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? What are your inputs and desired outputs? What schema are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both masks in your constructed condition specify that the search be performed anywhere in the column value:

```
... + ' and UPPER(col_FirstName) like ''%' + @firstName + '%'''
...
... + ' and UPPER(col_LastName) like ''%' + @lastName + '%'''
```

The percent sign in the mask stands for "any number of any characters". Placed before the search term, therefore, it would match a value where the search term (`@firstName`) is preceded by any number of characters. To specify that the `col_FirstName` value should *start* with the `@firstName` value (and possibly have an arbitrary number of characters afterwards), just remove the leading percent, i.e. like this:

```
... + ' and UPPER(col_FirstName) like ''' + @firstName + '%'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of these `IF`s you can do it in one query like so:

```
...
WHERE ...
  AND (@lastName  <> '' OR UPPER(col_LastName LIKE '%@lastName%')
  AND (@firstName <> '' OR UPPER(col_FirstName LIKE '%@firstName%')
```